# Does Python have C#/Java-style interfaces?

Tags: python, oop

I worked for a few months as a C# programmer, and got used to the idea of <strike>generics/templates</strike> interfaces, which I could pass to a library without caring how the object was created.

I'm about to start on a relatively large project, probably in python (I've written a lot of python before, but mostly my own code for data analysis etc), and was wondering if there exists a similar concept in this language? I've tried googling for it and not come up with much.

If the answer's no, that's fine, but in that case what do people generally do instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is you're looking for.  Templates and generics are completely different things (do you means like T4 templates?) Can you give some C# samples of what you'd like to do in Python?

Comment: I'd say the OP means C++ templates, the original inspiration for Java/C# generics

Comment: C++ templates are far more than generics though, and this invalidates the answers below should OP talk about C++ templates. I don't think so though, since only C# is mentioned and the phrasing "templates/generics" suggests OP isn't really aware of the difference.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for comments. I've just got back from my lunch and now my brain is telling me I should have said INTERFACES, not generics, or templates. Does that help?

Comment: Interfaces? We don't have no interfaces. We don't need no interfaces!  We don't need no stinking interfaces!!

Comment: Although off-point, I think the issue is that you needed to let go of your static-type thinking and embrace dynamic type-thinking. Python is OOP is C# but has different quirks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of interfaces is from Java, so hopefully that's close enough to what you mean...

There is no syntactic way to assert that a particular object has a set of methods and fields because Python uses [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing)/[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Duck_typing).  If you want to check whether an object has a certain method or field, you can:

- [Dig into it with reflection](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html) (this is the most work)
- Check for what you want in its `__dict__` (a dictionary of all of an
  object's members).  `MyObj.__dict__.hasKey(o)` is what you want, I think. (pretty easy)
- Just use the object and trust that you, your fellow developers, or your users have given you a proper object.  (Maximum easy, but dangerous)
- Or, do the above and wrap it in a try/except block.  (This will be familiar to Java programmers)

Designing a complex set of classes in Python is a very different experience from doing the same in C-like languages, so be prepared to do things you may be uncomfortable with (like option 3, above).  Good luck!

Comment: thanks - I knew that option 3 was available to me, but if I can convince my other team members not to use it, I will try :)

The rest is also useful. Thanks!

Comment: Probably a good idea, yeah.  I do that a lot in my personal stuff, but no one will die or lose money if I do it wrong.

Answer (score 17):

> If the answer's no, that's fine, but in that case what do people generally do instead?

[Duck Typing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuckTyping).

What's important is to approach Python by dropping the technical baggage of C#.

Learn Python as a **new** language.  Don't try to map concepts between Python and C#.  That way lies madness.

---

> "INTERFACES, not generics, or templates"

Doesn't matter.  All that static type declaration technology isn't necessary.  For that matter type casting in order to break the rules isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 5):

python is dynamically typed so (in most cases) there is no need for generics/templates.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking strictly about C#/Java-like interface, then the answer is simple. They are concepts that belong to statically typed languages and do not really apply to dynamic language such as Python.

The usual pythonic approach is to trust the objects you get and assume they have the necessary traits you need. Should they do not, you might expect runtime errors that can be handled or left for the caller. This matches the general dynamic nature of the language: if something goes wrong, you can expect it to surface at runtime.

Interfaces from Java or C#, on the other hand, are means for checking necessary preconditions (i.e. objects having certain methods) during **compilation**. This (arguably) trades off some of the runtime flexibility for increased safety of compile-time checks.

Note that it doesn't mean that **any** concept of interface has no place in dynamically typed language. In fact, Python has a slightly blurred notion of "meta-types" - such as iterables - that are often checked against, e.g. by verifying the presence of particular method(s):

```
def process_sequence(seq):
    if not hasattr(seq, '__iter__'):
        seq = [seq] # turn single element into iterable
    for elem in seq:
        process_element(elem)
```

This is conceptually similar to non-manifest interfaces from Go language. If you want to have your own iterable, you just implement the `__iter__` method - without explicitly stating that you **will** implement it (as in Java, where you would inherit from `List` class). Should anyone wants to check whether your object is indeed an iterable, they can verify whether the "contract" - i.e. having `__iter__` method - is indeed fulfilled. This is what andronikus described in their answer.

As a shameless plug, I can point out to the [pyduck](http://github.com/Xion/pyduck) library that I'm implementing. It aims to simplify (and maybe even standarize) verification of such "contracts" (via reflection) and make it slightly more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

[`zope.interface`](http://wiki.zope.org/Interfaces/FrontPage)

But most people don't use it.